# selecting tags for respective item

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get each item, and their respective tags with one query given a user_id.

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `description` mediumtext NOT NULL,
      `user_id` bigint(100) NOT NULL,
      `to_read` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `added_at` datetime NOT NULL,
      `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
      `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(100) NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `item_id` (`item_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Query:

```
SELECT tags.tag FROM tags WHERE tags.item_id = 5;

SELECT tag FROM tags t JOIN  items item ON t.item_id = item.id AND t.item_id = 5;
```

Which of my queries is correct to retrieve each items TAGS!

Comment: Your question is inconsistent. Do you want to query per user_id or item_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to get the tags, use

```
SELECT tag FROM tags WHERE item_id = 42;
```

To get the item AND the tags you need "Left outer join". Otherwise, items with no tags will be ignored:

```
SELECT tag FROM tags t LEFT JOIN  items item ON t.item_id = item.id AND t.item_id = 42;
```

Note, however, that might get the same tag multiple times. To avoid this, use `SELECT DISTINCT ...` instead.

**Edit:** The following statement returns one row per item, with an additional column that concatenates all tags of that item:

```
SELECT items.*, 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag) 
       FROM tags 
      WHERE tags.item_id = items.id) AS tags 
FROM items WHERE items.user_id = 0;
```

In case that you decide to switch to a three-table layout with a `tags_items` table:

```
SELECT items.*, 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag) FROM tags 
       WHERE tags.id = tags_items.tag_id) AS tags 
  FROM items 
  LEFT JOIN tags_items 
         ON tags_items.item_id = items.id 
 WHERE items.user_id = 0;
```

Comment: Currently I seem to get two tags for the same item, sort of too many rows. Do you think that group by can be used?

Comment: @N000b101 Can you provide some example data and the desired result? Group by might be the solution, but I would have to guess the answer if I don't know exacly what you need

Comment: @N000b101 If one item has multiple tags, you should get one result row for each item/tag-combination. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Maja can you see how those are grouped, not sure if the GROUP_CONCAT does that.

Comment: Ok, so you want one row for each item, and the result should contain a single cell with all tags concatenated?

Comment: It is possible. And there are (rare) situation where you can need such a feature. It depends on what you wanna do with the data. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Maja, I keep getting an error, that : SQL Error (1051): Uknown table 'items'

Comment: Where does this problem appear? Try replacing it with `item` (no `s`).

Comment: Maja, is it possible to run one query like this one, and pick out lets say untagged items as well? Or should I do a merge like UNION?

Comment: Since the last query uses `LEFT JOIN`, untagged items should also be found. Union is not the right choice for that.

Comment: Currently it gives me only one result, the tagged item. The others do not appear.

Comment: BTW, is my table design good in practice? Or should I have done this differently. Given that an item can have many tags. Thanks a lot Maja!

Comment: I think the table design is good, but the additional `user_id` field in `tags` is not neccessary since you can query it by joining it with the item table. Generally, you should follow the rule that "Information is only stored once to make inconsistencies within the database impossible." What if you need to update the item's user_id, you'll have to update all tag-user_id's as well, which is a bad design. To the error: I'll need to know the input data and output data to help you fix that since the query should do the correct thing.

Comment: What about two items sharing similar tag? Is this correct still in terms of design.

Comment: BTW, user_id, doesn't change that often. In fact, it remains the same all the time, since the user only changes the other stuff, user_id = AUTO_INCREMENT per member. UID is also once per user.

Comment: Maja, how can I make this work well, for instance include all the untagged items + the tagged items in the one query result, using your GROUP_CONCAT snippet.

Comment: Maja, this is my code now: "

SELECT items.*, 
GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag ORDER BY tags.tag) AS tags 
FROM tags LEFT JOIN  items ON tags.item_id = items.id 
AND items.user_id = 0;

"

Comment: Since you use `tags` as your main table (it occurs before your items-table), you have to change the join to a `RIGHT JOIN`. Right Join = all rows of the table at the right are present. Left Join = all items of the left table are present. I corrected my answer.

Comment: The user with items.user_id = 0, has 3 items. Yet, when I run your SQL-snippet I get only one item, instead of three items. I am aware that the other two are untagged.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83756/discussion-between-n000b101-and-maja).